# asp.net : I wanted to know how to insert '\n' on the label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am just simply creating a web application.
I wanted to insert a line break in a label

for example

```
label1.Text = "I AM HERE" + "\n" + "I AM NOW HERE";
```

I wanted to print it as

```
I AM HERE

I AM NOW HERE
```

But, it is not working... I don't know why...

I even tried

```
label1.Text = "I AM HERE" + '\n' + "I AM NOW HERE";
```

its not working.. What should I do....

Comment: You can accept any of the answers by clicking the checkmark. This applies to your other questions too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `<br />` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

To insert line breaks use the 
 tags.

To insert spaces use the  .

```
Label1.Text="First line<br/>Second line with &nbsp;&nbsp; more spaces"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<br />` tag. This will create a breaking space (or newline) in the label, e.g.:

```
label1.Text = "I AM HERE<br />I AM NOW HERE";
```

---

As a **side note**. You do not need to seperate out `\n`'s in your coding. In future where you can use it, you can simply go:

```
"I AM HERE\nI AM NOW HERE";
```

And this will add in the new line for you.